# Wrapping a React Route render component in a HOC

Tags: react-router

I wrapped the Profile component in a HOC that is supposed to redirect the user to certain page once he logs out while in this route, like so :

```
           <Route
                path="/profile/:username"
                  render={props=> withAuth(<Profile currentUser={currentUser} {...props} />)}
            />
```

I get this Error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent, displayName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

this is My HOC:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


export default function withAuth(ComponentToBeRendered) {
    class Authenticate extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            if (this.props.isAuthenticated === false) {
                this.props.history.push("/signin");
            }
        }
        componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
            if (nextProps.isAuthenticated === false) {
                this.props.history.push("/signin");
            }
        }
        render() {
            
            return ComponentToBeRendered ;
        }
    }
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            isAuthenticated: state.currentUser.isAuthenticated
        }
    }
    
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticate);
}
```

This is My Profile Component:

```
import MessageList from "../containers/MessageList";
import UserAside from "./UserAside";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectTheUser } from '../store/selectors'

const Profile = props => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <MessageList {...props} />
            <UserAside
                {...props} />
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    userToVisit: selectTheUser(props.match.params.username)(state)
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HOC

```
render() {
    
    return <ComponentToBeRendered {...this.props}/> ;
}
```

In your Router

```
   const ProfileWithAuth = withAuth(Profile)
   <Route
        path="/profile/:username"
          render={props=> (<ProfileWithAuth currentUser={currentUser} {...props}/>)}
    />
```